# Yes/No Magento module installation CE/EE

Tags: magento, module, installation, enterprise

I would like to know, whether we can install Magento Free modules in Enterprise edition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do it easly in magento connect platform https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/

There are many free extension for Magento EE (Enterprise Edition)